# Música Aleatoria con Drive

Tags: javascript, html5, google-drive, audio

No sé casi nada de Programación pero sí sé qué es lo que necesito, lo que sucede es que no encuentro la solución a mi problema y ya probé pero no logro que funcione.

Tengo un Reproductor de Audio en una página que estoy creando (HTML5, CSS y Javascript)

Sucede que tiene un listado de temas todos continuados. Se reproduce a pedido del usuario si le da play si no no suena. Hasta ahí todo bien.

Yo quisiera poder hacer que sea aleatorio. Es decir crear una lista de temas, ya sé cómo hacerlo, que cuando el usuario le de play se reproduzca cualquier tema de esa lista y que continúe con cualquier otro tema de la misma lista.

Estuve probando con otros códigos distintos al que ya tengo y funcionan con música de archive.org pero yo tengo la música en Google Drive y no logro saber cómo es que tengo que poner lo que sería la carpeta principal y los archivos en lista como dice el código entonces tal vez, se pueda modificar el código que ya tengo para que funcione de forma aleatoria... Entiendo que se llama Math Random en Javascript pero no sé cómo se hace.

Les dejo el código que tengo acá para que lo vean y me digan qué le agrego o qué le saco. Funcionar funciona perfecto.

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript' />
<script>
  //<![CDATA[
  var audio;
  var playlist;
  var tracks;
  var current;
  initaudio();

  function initaudio() {
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = 1;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      link = $(this);
      current = link.parent().index();
      runaudio(link, audio[0])
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
      current++;
      if (current > len) {
        current = 0;
        link = playlist.find('a')[0]
      } else {
        link = playlist.find('a')[current]
      }
      runaudio($(link), audio[0])
    })
  }

  function runaudio(link, player) {
    player.src = link.attr('href');
    par = link.parent();
    par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    audio[0].load();
    audio[0].play()
  }
  //]]>
</script>

<div id='player'>
  <audio controls='' id='audio' preload='auto' tabindex='0' type='audio/mpeg'>
    <source src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=13n0YMbhgMISFSrn4eTJOujVqCKaSdgLt' type='audio/mp3'/>
    </audio>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="divspoiler">
  <a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="if (this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display != '') { this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display = ''; } else { this.parentNode.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.display = 'none';}">Écoutez Paris &#9660;</a>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="spoiler" style="display: none;">
    <br />
    <br />
    <ul id='playlist'>
      <li class='active'><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=13n0YMbhgMISFSrn4eTJOujVqCKaSdgLt'>Paris sera toujours Paris</a></li>
      <li><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1XjKa3jTfRr--AE7RGH3ftFTkxJ9uPgFs'>Paris canaille</a></li>
      <li><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1sGM7VraFXczyMs8dzFHmBrkHW5kW4EHx'>À Paris</a></li>
      <li><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1eBi_uZj_enFGZNN8AgiGm7dJvrLOah2G'>Dans mon Paris</a></li>
      <li><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1K5tPwa4oxD8XO0JiyT4WMgdvAuR29zo3'>Champs Elysées</a></li>
      <li><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1iFFxRp6_OXA4kIQYYmhO9t8kvVOsdKkb'>Sous le ciel de Paris</a></li>
      <li><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=15-rdRJg4QjIpC4kyQrgqyHoXiBJhNszs'>La parisienne</a></li>
      <li><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1SJcSVrrJbNYmk_jTgp2HCWa7tE_jc2QO'>I love Paris / J'aime Paris avec Nikky Yanofsky</a></li>
      <li><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1XZgQ5m8kYj5ifSriMTZgy5AbUSWE5VAk-2'>La romance de Paris avec Thomas Dutronc</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=14EyWP-uNpXW28HJvkv9GHnXL4ciSk9WN'></a>La complainte de la butte</li>
      <li><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1ncMt_L8jcVSJb9gnLKqTY29PExi-QUXP'>J'aime Paris au mois de mai avec Charles Aznavour</a></li>
      <li><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1LWG52Ee6HkW1_sygzlAgD2wLJjYebPiT'>Paris, l'après midi</a></li>
      <li><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1bEl2CD1uW9SJj1Cwpv-YQby44dWhHM-J'>J'ai deux amours</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

No logré que funcionara con la solución que me pasaron. Supongo que me enredé sola porque es demasiado técnico y no sé nada de Programación.

Por el contrario, logré modificar el código Javascript que tenía para que funcionara de forma directa y hacerlo aleatorio. Encontré dónde es que estaba la parte que iba de un tema al otro y la hice aleatoria a pedido del usuario. Si quiere puede ser como una lista directa y si no aleatorio por medio de una casilla de verificación.

El código me quedo muy corto y sencillo. Comprensible al cien por ciento para alguien que no sabe de Programación, como yo.

Comment: Hola @simja.82. Estuve analizando tu código. El proceso está bien, pero va a ser necesario modificarlo un poco para lograr el efecto que deseas. Ahora mismo te estoy redactando una explicación  en el área de respuesta de cómo se hace con ejemplo ejecutable. El código JavaScript estará fuertemente comentado para con el objeto de explicar bien cada del proceso.

Comment: Hola David. Gracias por responder. Sigo tratando de saber cómo hacer.

En códigos que encontré arman las listas con una parte que dice "var list [
Enlace 1 - Nombre para mostrar;
y siguen así
]" y después todos los archivos como items entre corchetes. 
Lo que sucede es que hay una parte antes, que tiene la carpeta principal y en mi caso yo no tengo una carpeta principal, es decir en Google Drive sí hay pero no puedo separar los enlaces en principal y archivos MP3.
No entiendo lenguaje técnico. Dime qué cambio/agrego/elimino? Confío en que funcione. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Hola @simja.82. Ya estoy cerca de desocuparme. Aproximadamente, en media hora publico la explicación.

Comment: @simja.85 Listo, la puedes revisar. Revisaré periódicamente la respuesta para añadirle mejoras.

Answer (score 2):

## Reproductor musical

> Estuve analizando el problema y el código está bien, excepto por el hecho de no puedes desplegar el menú de forma viable y obviamente, la **reproducción aleatoria** (al menos, en las pruebas realicé).

Ahora bien, para lograr el efecto deseado, que es la **reproducción aleatoria** de audio debemos aplicar algunos cambios propuestos en esta publicación.

Para ellos vamos a definir las siguientes siete (07) funciones:

- **esEnlace(*_esEnlace*):** es una función de tipo *booleana* en el que se pasa un elemento HTML como parámetro. Su objetivo es evaluar si el elemento es un enlace. Ejemplo de uso:

```js
  if (esEnlace(enlace)) {
      // Instrucciones
  }
```

- **esAudio(*_esAudio*):** es una función de tipo *booleana* en el que se pasa un elemento HTML como parámetro. Su objetivo es evaluar si el elemento en cuestión es un elemento de `audio` . Ejemplo de uso:

```js
  if (esAudio(audio)) {
      // Instrucciones
  }
```

- **urlLista(*_selector*):** esta función devuelve un `Array` de *urls* a partir de una lista de enlaces que apuntan a un archivo de audio. Cada *url* representa cada *audio*. Ejemplo de uso:

```js
  const urls = urlLista("#playlist a");
```

- **reproducirTodo( *_audio* ):** esta función permite reproducir de forma secuencial una lista de reproducción creada a partir de una secuencia de enlaces.
- **reproducirAleatorio( *_urls, _audio* ):** esta función reproduce de forma aleatoria la lista de reproducción obtenido a partir de una secuencia de enlaces que apuntan a archivos de audio.
- **seleccionarEnlace(*_clase, _selector, _ruta*):** esta función permite marcar el enlace del audio que se está reproduciendo.
- **inicializar( *_audio* ):** tal y como su nombre lo indica, es una función hecha para inicializar la reproducción de la *lista de reproducción*. Se utilizará para iniciar la reproducción del próximo audio al terminar la reproducción del audio anterior.

También se debe modificar un poco la estructura HTML para el audio, por lo que propongo algo parecido a esto:

```html
<audio id="audio" controls="" src="http://dominio.com/audio.mp3" data-aleatorio="no"></audio>
```

En el que se implementa el atributo `data-aleatorio` en el elemento audio por si queremos una reproducción aleatoria o no.

### Ejemplo

Los comentarios en el siguiente *Snippet* son bastante extensos con el objeto de explicar el funcionamiento de todo el `script`. Por lo tanto, es importante leerlo para comprender las acciones que realiza.

```js
// Posición del audio:
var posicion = 0;

// Definimos una función para comprobar si el elemento
// HTML seleccionado es un enlace:
const esEnlace = (_esEnlace) => {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(_esEnlace) === "[object HTMLAnchorElement]";
};

// Definimos una función para comprobar si el elemento
// HTML es un audio:
const esAudio = (_esAudio) => {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(_esAudio) === "[object HTMLAudioElement]";
};

// Definimos una función para construir un array de rutas
// a partir de las rutas de los enlaces:
const urlLista = (_selector) => {
  if (typeof _selector === "undefined")
    return;

  // Capturamos los elementos que necesitamos procesar,
  // fundamentalmente enlace:
  const enlaces = document.querySelectorAll(_selector);
  const urls = [];

  // Nos aseguramos que que se hayan capturados los enlaces
  if (enlaces.length)
    enlaces.forEach(enlace => {
      // Comprobamos que el elementos capturado es un enlace para 
      // obtener su ruta e incorporarla en el Array «urls»:
      if (esEnlace(enlace))
        urls.push(enlace.href);
    });

  // La función devolverá un array con las urls obtenidas
  // de los enlaces:
  return urls;
}

// Definimos esta función para reproducir toda la lista de 
// reproducción secuencialmente:
const reproducirTodo = (_audio) => {
  if (!esAudio(_audio))
    return;

  let
    // Obtenemos un Array de rutas a partir de "#playlist a" que serán
    // almacenadas en el Array «urls»:
    urls = urlLista("#playlist a"),

    // Definimos la variable ruta en la que se almacenará
    // una ruta válida de audio:
    ruta;

  // Comprobamos que la posición marcada sea menor que urls.length
  // para asegurarnos obtener una ruta válida de audio:
  if (posicion < urls.length) {
    ruta = urls[posicion];
    _audio.src = ruta;
    _audio.play();

    // Actualizamos la posición para seleccionar el siguiente audio
    // a reproducir:
    posicion++;

    // Devolvemos una ruta válida de audio:
    return ruta;
  }
};

// Definimos la función «reproducirAleatorio» cuyo objetivo es
// reproducir el audio de forma aleatoria:
const reproducirAleatorio = (_urls, _audio) => {
  let num = _urls.length;

  // Obtenemos un número aleatoreamente en función de la longitud
  // de las rutas obtenidas:
  num = Math.random() * num;

  // Con esto, haremos que el número aleatorio obtenido sea entero:
  num = Math.ceil(num);

  // Le restamos 1 a num para acceder a las posiciones 0
  // y última del array de urls:
  num--;

  // Actualizar la posición del audio:
  posicion = num;

  // Se valida si «_audio» es un elemento de audio:
  if (esAudio(_audio)) {
    _audio.src = _urls[posicion];
    _audio.play();
  }

  return _urls[posicion];
};

// Marcar el enlace que tiene el audio que se está reproduciendo:
const seleccionarEnlace = (_clase, _selector, _ruta) => {
  // Se evalúa si el parámetro _clase no es un «string»:
  if (typeof _clase !== "string")
    return;

  const enlaces = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  // Evaluar los enlaces de la lista de reproducción 
  // para quitarle la clase «_clase» si es que la tiene definida:
  if (enlaces.length)
    enlaces.forEach(a => {
      if (a.classList.contains(_clase))
        a.classList.remove(_clase);
    });

  // Si no se definieron parámetros en la función se termina 
  // la ejecución del resto del código:
  if (typeof _selector !== "string" && typeof _ruta !== "string")
    return;

  let
    enlace = document.querySelector(`${_selector}[href="${_ruta}"]`);


  // Previamente, se evalúa si el elemento es nulo:
  if (enlace === null)
    return;

  // Se evalúa que sea un enlace para marcarla como seleccionada
  // si el audio que se encuentra señalado en el atributo «href»
  // se encuentra reproduciéndose:
  if (esEnlace(enlace))
    enlace.classList.add(_clase);

  // Si el audio señalado en el audio ha sido marcado como
  // reproduciéndose la función devolverá un true:
  return enlace.classList.contains(_clase);
};


const inicializar = (_audio) => {
  if (!esAudio(_audio))
    return;

  let
    // Obtenemos un array (arreglo) de rutas válidas de audio
    // a partir de los enlaces de audio:
    urls = urlLista("#playlist a"),

    // Evaluamos si el atributo «data-aleatorio» del elemento audio 
    // está definido como "si" o "no". Si es si la reproducción de 
    // será aleatoria, de lo contrario, será secuencial:
    url = (_audio.dataset.aleatorio === "si") ? reproducirAleatorio(urls, audio) : reproducirTodo(_audio);

  // Marcamos el enlace de audio para que el usuario
  // sepa que se está reproduciendo:
  seleccionarEnlace("selected", "a", url);
}

// Si el usuario elige uno de los enlaces de la lista
// de reproducción:
playlist.onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Se verifica si el elemento seleccionado es un enlace
  // para reproducir el audio en el reproductor:
  if (esEnlace(e.target)) {
    audio.src = e.target.href;
    audio.play();
  }

  // Obtenemos las urls a partir de los enlaces:
  let urls = urlLista("#playlist a");

  // Obtenemos el índice del array «urls» donde se encuentran
  // almacenadas las rutas de audio a partir de una ruta 
  // específica:
  posicion = urls.indexOf(audio.src);
}


// Evento capturado para cuando finalice la reproducción de
// un audio pase al siguiente de forma aleatoria o no, según
// sea el caso:
audio.onended = function() {
  inicializar(this);
};

// Evento capturado para seleccionar el enlace
// que se está reproduciendo:
audio.onplaying = () => {
  seleccionarEnlace("selected", "a", audio.src);
};

// Evento "pause" capturado para quitar la la clase
// "selected" al enlace que se está reproduciendo:
audio.onpause = () => {
  seleccionarEnlace("selected");
}

aleatorio.onclick = function() {
  if (!esAudio(audio))
    return;

  let data = audio.dataset;

  // Evaluamos mediante un operador ternario:
  data.aleatorio = (this.checked) ? "si" : "no";
}

lista.onclick = (e) => {
  if (esEnlace(e.target)) {
    // Cuando el usuario presiona sobre la lista de reproducción
    // cambia la figura con forma de triángulo como plegado / desplegado:
    e.target.classList.toggle("lista__enlace--desplegado");

    // Para el caso anterior, al mismo tiempo se intercambia entre
    // establecer y no establecer la clase "playlist--desplegar",
    // dando coomo resultado la sensación visual de despliegue de la
    // lista de reproducción:
    playlist.classList.toggle("playlist--desplegar");

    // Se verifica si es un elemento de audio:
    if (esAudio(audio)) {

      // Se evalúa si se está reproduciendo para reproducirlo al desplegar
      // la lista de reproducción:
      if (audio.paused && playlist.classList.contains("playlist--desplegar"))
        inicializar(audio);
    }
  }
}

// Si se llegase a recargar la página y se mantuviese
// activada la opción «Activar Modo Aleatorio» debemos 
// asegurarnos de que se cumpla. Para ello, vamos a utilizar
// una función autoejecutable (aunque no es obligatorio):
(function() {
  // Evaluamos si el modo aleatorio está activado
  // a la vez que «audio» sea un elemento de audio:
  if (aleatorio.checked && esAudio(audio))
    audio.dataset.aleatorio = "si";
}());
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");

:root {
  --color: #5e5c5c;
  --fondo: rgba(94, 92, 92, 0.03);
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  
  /* Figuras: */
  --plegado: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 50%, 0% 100%);
  --desplegado: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 50% 100%);
}

a {
  color: var(--color);
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color);
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.spoiler {
  background-color: var(--fondo);
}

audio {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 300ms ease;
  min-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: max-content;
}
label:hover {
  background-color: var(--fondo);
  color: var(--color);
}

.selected {
  color: #008000;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 300ms ease;
}
.selected::after {
  content: " (reproduciendo...)";
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  transition: 300ms ease;
  color: #f06600;
}

.grupo-botones {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.grupo-botones button {
  background-color: var(--color);
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.playlist {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateX(-10deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
}
.playlist--desplegar {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  animation: 300ms ease desplegar 1;
}
.playlist__item {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
  min-height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.playlist__item:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.aleatorio ~ span {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.lista__enlace {
  --diametro: 13px;
}
.lista__enlace::before {
  content: "";
  transition: 300ms ease;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--color);
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: calc(var(--diametro) * 0.8);
  height: var(--diametro);
  clip-path: var(--plegado);
}
.lista__enlace--desplegado::before {
  clip-path: var(--desplegado);
  width: var(--diametro);
  height: calc(var(--diametro) * 0.8);
}

.content {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: calc( 100% - 20px );
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: var(--fondo);
  border: 1px solid;
}

/* Área de animaciones */
@keyframes desplegar {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-10deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='player'>
  <audio id="audio" controls="" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=13n0YMbhgMISFSrn4eTJOujVqCKaSdgLt" data-aleatorio=""></audio>
</div>

<div class="grupo-botones">
  <label for="aleatorio">
    <input type="checkbox" id="aleatorio" class="aleatorio">
    <span>Activar Modo Aleatorio</span>
  </label>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="content">

  <!-- Lista de reproducción -->
  <div class="spoiler">
    <!-- Menú de la lista de reproducción -->
    <div class="lista" id="lista">
      <a href="#" class="lista__enlace">Écoutez Paris</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Lista de reproducción-->
    <ul id='playlist' class="playlist">
      <li class="playlist__item">
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=13n0YMbhgMISFSrn4eTJOujVqCKaSdgLt'>Paris sera toujours Paris</a></li>
      <li class="playlist__item">
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1XjKa3jTfRr--AE7RGH3ftFTkxJ9uPgFs'>Paris canaille</a></li>
      <li class="playlist__item">
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1sGM7VraFXczyMs8dzFHmBrkHW5kW4EHx'>À Paris</a></li>
      <li class="playlist__item">
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1eBi_uZj_enFGZNN8AgiGm7dJvrLOah2G'>Dans mon Paris</a></li>
      <li class="playlist__item">
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1K5tPwa4oxD8XO0JiyT4WMgdvAuR29zo3'>Champs Elysées</a></li>
      <li class="playlist__item">
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1iFFxRp6_OXA4kIQYYmhO9t8kvVOsdKkb'>Sous le ciel de Paris</a></li>
      <li class="playlist__item">
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=15-rdRJg4QjIpC4kyQrgqyHoXiBJhNszs'>La parisienne</a></li>
      <li class="playlist__item">
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1SJcSVrrJbNYmk_jTgp2HCWa7tE_jc2QO'>I love Paris / J'aime Paris avec Nikky Yanofsky</a></li>
      <li class="playlist__item">
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=14EyWP-uNpXW28HJvkv9GHnXL4ciSk9WN'>La complainte de la butte</a></li>
      <li class="playlist__item">
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1ncMt_L8jcVSJb9gnLKqTY29PExi-QUXP'>J'aime Paris au mois de mai avec Charles Aznavour</a></li>
      <li class="playlist__item"><a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1LWG52Ee6HkW1_sygzlAgD2wLJjYebPiT'>Paris, l'après midi</a></li>
      <li class="playlist__item">
        <a href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1bEl2CD1uW9SJj1Cwpv-YQby44dWhHM-J'>J'ai deux amours</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

No olvides presionar la casilla de verificación «Activar Modo Aleatorio» y el enlace «Pantalla completa» del *Snippet* anterior para apreciar mejor los resultados.

> **Nota:** esta publicación será actualizada periódicamente. Se documenta fundamentalmente el código escrito en *JavaScript* dado que el problema se enfoca en la misma.

> **Le puede interesar** si desea traducir el código a uno para navegadores más antiguo puede utilizar el [siguiente transpilador](https://babeljs.io/repl).

Comment: En lo que tenga un poco más de tiempo revisaré esta publicación para realizar las correcciones o mejoras que deban que hacerse.